# In report designer, copy a formula from one report to another

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using VS 2008.

I want to copy a formula field from one report to other.

I tried copy/paste and checked other design options but couldn't succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to set the formula at runtime for a report or copy/paste the formula field into another report?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try dragging the formula into a section in the report, and then copying and pasting that into a section in the other report. When it pastes, if the formula doesn't already exist, it should copy it.

You'll need to repeat it for any formulas referenced by the formula, since they won't be copied automatically.

Comment: This is my life saving tip! It saved me so much time.